# how to pass image for popup into jquery without hard coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameters

I'm learning jQuery and I need to figure out how to not hard-code. So I have 2 different divs (master and popup) being populated by an array. The first div (master) is visible and the second (popup) that I'm using as a pop-up is hidden. On the view, you see an image in the div( master) and when it is clicked, I have a jQuery function that triggers the hidden div (popup) to show up.

Now if 10 items are gotten from the array, I have 10 images displaying but when I click on any image (including the first), only the first image in the array populates the popup div.

I hard-coded a 'fix' based on my current jQuery knowledge but this is repetitive code which means I can only have the amount of divs declared in my jQuery. I need to find a way that each image displays it's corresponding popup without having to hard code it in all the way

My html code:
Master div:

```
<div class="master">
 <div id="imgprop"><img src="IMGCOMP/bgggg.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" height="238" width="238" /></div>
 <div id="ps1" class="popit1" #hard coded popit id>
  <section>
   <span>IMAGE TITLE</span>
   <span id="zoom"></span>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="master">
 <div id="imgprop"><img src="IMGCOMP/bgg.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" height="238" width="238" /></div>
 <div id="ps1" class="popit2" #hard coded popit id>
  <section>
   <span>IMAGE TITLE</span>
   <span id="zoom"></span>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Popup div:

```
<div id="GbgPopup1" #hard coded gbpopup id>
 <div id="GPopupcontent">
  <div class="closeit"></div>
  <span class="ecs_tooltip_">Press esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
  <div class="image">
   <img src="IMGCOMP/bgggg.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" height="400" width="430" />
  </div>           
 </div>
</div>

<div id="GbgPopup2" #hard coded gbpopup id>
 <div id="GPopupcontent">
  <div class="closeit"></div>
  <span class="ecs_tooltip_">Press esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
  <div class="image">
   <img src="IMGCOMP/bgg.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" height="400" width="430" />
  </div>           
 </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    #hard coded
    $(".popit1").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup1(); // function show popup
            }); // .5 second
    return false;
    });
    $(".popit2").click(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                loadPopup2(); // function show popup
                }); // .5 second
        return false;
        });


    /* event for close the popup */
    $("div.closeit").hover(
                    function() {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip_').show();
                    },
                    function () {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip_').hide();
                    }
                );

    $("div.closeit").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup();  // function close pop up
        }
    });


  var popupStatus = 0; // set value
  #hard coded
  function loadPopup1() {
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            $("#GbgPopup1").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }
    }
    function loadPopup2() {
            if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
                $("#GbgPopup2").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
                popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
            }
        }

    #hard coded
    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#GbgPopup1").fadeOut("normal");
            $("#GbgPopup2").fadeOut("normal");
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }
});
```

Every help and more jQuery resources to help improve my knowledge is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing Martin's answer, I was able to dig more into jQuery and adapt his answer to make it work.

All I did was move the code in `loadpopup()` function into the parent `.click()` function, change the `$(".popit").click` for the div(master) to `$(".master").click` to effectively select the whole div, used the `$(this)` so I can get the current clicked `img` in the master div and then replaced the `src` in the popup div

```
var popupStatus = 0; // set value

$(".master").click(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var popup = $("#GbgPopup");
        popup.find("img").attr("src", imgSrc);
        popup.fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1          
//return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question right. Do you want to know how to take the picture source from master and put it into the popup?

To get the src of the picture in master you can do this:

```
$(".popit").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(this); // function show popup
        }); // .5 second
        return false;
});

function loadPopup(clickedElement) {
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        // first find the img tag from master
        var imgSrc = $(clickedElement).parent().find("img").attr("src");
        var popup = $("#GbgPopup");
        popup.find("img").attr("src", imgSrc);
        popup.fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if there are bugs in the code, I did not run it. I trust you can remove the hard coded part from your code again.

Comment: was able to adapt this to make it work, thank you @MartinVerner

Answer (score 0):

create a master div and use http://api.jquery.com/appendto/ to dinamically generate every popup passing only the image and the counter

ie:

`function generatePop(image, counter) {
   var html = '<div class="ecs_tooltip_" id="pop"'+counter+"><img src=...    </div>';
   $(html).appendTo('#master-div');
    }`